# Use Pinterest JS with non-standard Pinterest button

Tags: wordpress, plugins, pinterest

I want to use a custom Pinterest button.

Currently I have the button graphic set in a wordpress plugin with the following line from the PHP file:

```
$pinterest_button = '<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='.get_permalink().'&media='.wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ).'&description='.substr(urlencode(get_the_title()), 0, 200).'" target="_blank" title="Pin this on Pinterest"><img src="'.plugins_url('pinterest.png', __FILE__).'" width="33" /></a> ';
```

I'm then loading the Pinterest JS file elsewhere.

The problem is that the Pinterest JS hijacks my specified custom Pinterest icon (pinterest.png) and turns it into the standard "Pin It" button so it then doesn't fit in with the rest of my buttons.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?